# Too many files open in system when outputting to a txt file in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to make a program that goes through a text file and counts word usage in Java, using Eclipse. The program works, but I want to save the output values to a text file. I am using this bit of code to do that:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

I have used

```
throws FileNotFoundException
```

to get rid of the file not found exception.

When I run the program, I get an error that says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: output.txt 
    (Too many open files in system)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
at nGram.HashMapFun.main(HashMapFun.java:66)
```

I made an output.txt file in the java project, so I don't know why the program can't find it. The output is from a HashMap.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you closing each file after you open it for reading / word counting?. Are you closing the buffers?. Show us the entire code.

Comment: There is a limit of open file reference per process, your code seem to not close files and keep opening many files hitting that limit

Comment: Sounds like you have a resource leak somewhere

Comment: Are you closing stream?

Comment: @JigarJoshi - I think that's the issue. He might not be closing the files / Streams after reading them. Too many references..

Answer (score 1):

> I have used
>    `throws FileNotFoundException`
>    to get rid of the file not found exception.

Listen, using `throws` don't get rid of the Excetion.

You need to catch the thrown exception. But as long as there is an exception you cannot continue from that point, until you skip that stage using conditional statement.

```
try {
   // code here
} catch (Exception e) {
   // message here
}
```

UNIX OS and such other OS would limit each process to a number of files to be loaded at a time. So, I think where you're using a Reader or Scanner you need to close them.

Use this

```
scanner.Close();
```

I am unaware of your scanner of fileReader code. So, you can replate this with that. Once you're using this code, the file with whom you're done working would be closed and the link to it would be closed. Thus enabling you to open a new file.

Answer (score 1):

import java.io.*;
public class Hello 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        /*the File class uses a constructor File("absolute URI")
         * example linux/OSX/Unix
         * File("home/user/workspace/hello.txt);
         * 
         * example Windows
         * File("C:/Documents/hello);+
         */

        File file = new File("/home/nirban/hello.txt");

        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
        System.setOut(out);
        out.println("Hello this is my file");
        out.close();
        fis.close();        
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

the input/output stream needs to be closed after the operation,
if the stream is not closed then the JVM keeps the file in the jvm process
to check the existence of the file LINUX

$ ps -e |grep java

(pid) ?     00:03:42 java

$lsof -p (pid)

this will list all the files and process run by JVM

Thanks and Enjoy.................

Answer (score 0):

Close the FileOutputStream and PrintStream. It will solve your problem. Try below code

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fos);
System.setOut(out);

out.close();
fos.close();
```